# Lotus Notes - How can I retrieve user actions

Tags: logging, lotus-notes

Is there a log mechanism in LotusNotes (v8.5) that documents all/some of the actions taken by users, like sending or deleting emails? And if not, how can I add support for that?

I'm fairly new to this particular piece of software, so please go easy on me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built-in that gets to that level of detail.  There is a message tracking feature on the server that can get you a lot of information about mail that is sent, but nothing for tracking deletions.  There is a third party product called SecurTrak made by a company called ExtraComm that would give you that, and more.  It is built using an interface in the Notes API called the "Extension Manager", which exposes low level events on the Domino server.  There's a project called "Trigger Happy" posted on the open source OpenNTF.org web site that implements a framework for using Extension Manager events to trigger Domino agents, so if a full-blown auditing product like SecurTrak is more than you need, you could try having a Domino developer use Trigger Happy to build only the custom monitoring that you really need.